# Where should I look for food-grade nitrogen fills?

Tags: cold-brew

I'm looking for an ~100% N<sub>2</sub> fill for nitro cold brew coffee and I'm having a hard time finding a supplier who sells food grade N<sub>2</sub> in consumer quantities. Any advice for companies in United States who sell food grade N<sub>2</sub>?

Comment: Why 100% nitro?  Beer gas blend is usually 25/75 CO2/N2.  You might have an easier time finding that at your local compressed gas supplier.  Are you solely talking about making coffee or a coffee beer?  If its the former your question may need to get migrated to a different SE site.

Comment: Solely coffee. However it's brewed at home and kegged...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked to homebrewing supply stores looking for "Guinness mix" or "beer gas" pre-filled bottles for sale. While this isn't a pure 100% mix, it's about 75/25 or 70/30 and usually means the supplier mixed it for them. After a lot of digging at homebrew suppliers, I found that one of their suppliers does smaller batch orders, which can be difficult since fequently breweries sign up for a delivery schedule with large gas suppliers.

The gas supplier is an industrial welding and gas supply store -- don't let "industrial" in the name dissuade you from calling and asking about food/medical grade. This industrial supplier also has food grade tank exchange.